# Trying to click an image and open a modal ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Thanks in advance, I just started coding a few weeks ago and I can't figure this out.
I have been trying to set up where you click an image and it opens a modal that is matched by the img tag, and that modal click event will in turn call a method.  Problem is that I can't seem to get the onclick event to open the modal, i think once i get that to work I can get the method calls to work.  I have tried a bunch of things and can't seem to figure out how to get it to pop up,

here is the JS/ajax

```
$('#img').click(function(){
$('#vendingModal').dialog('open');
 return false;
});


$('#vendingModal').click(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
var element = $(event.relatedTarget);
var inventoryId = element.data('inventory-id');
var modal = $(this); 
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'inventory/' + inventoryId
}).success(function (inventory) {
    modal.find('#inventory-id').text(inventory.inventoryId);
    modal.find('#inventory-name').text(inventory.inventoryName);
    modal.find('#inventory-price').text(inventory.price);
    modal.find('#inventory-count').text(inventory.count);

});
});
```

here is the jsp

```
 <%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<div class="column2" id="inventoryGrid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 offset-3-12">
                <div class="pic morph">
                    <img id="item1" src="img/item1.jpg" alt="3    Musketeers" title="3 Musketeers" class="img-rounded img-responsive"   style="width:128px;height:128px">
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The click event is linked to the wrong element.
"$('#img')" will point to an "img" id. Your image, however, has the id "item1", so try with $('#item1').click(function(){

Comment: was hoping to just assign the click event to all the img tags, but I did give your answer a try and it just returned undefined, ty the more stuff I try the more I learn. I did comment out the first click section as well, still nothing.

Comment: If you just want images, then use $('img')...Regarding the $('#item1') selector, it should have worked. However, without seeing the vendingModal code, I cannot know where the "undefined" problem comes from

Comment: tyvm, you solved one problem, I will work a while on trying to answer the rest.

Comment: /hangs head..... another thing that helps is having the vendingModalFragment in the right package.... i some how created it in one of my other projects....

Comment: Yeah, we've all been through that :D